# How to parse base64 data received from controller using javascript or Apex (ParsingWord document in salesforce ) . Please suggest!

Tags: apex, visualforce

/*Controller.cls*/

```
public class docxVFcontroller {
public string base64text {get; set;}
public void getFile()
        {
         Attachment a = [Select Body from attachment where name like '%word.docx%' limit 1];
         blob b = a.body;

         base64text  = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(b);
        }
}
```

/*VF page*/
...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var base64 = '{!base64text}';
```

/* assuming on click of command button i have this base64 text.Please suggest an idea on how would i process this base64 data to json or som other format to process further. Or is there any way to process it in controller only to a json String */

```
</script>
```

Comment: I think basically you're trying to do a base64decode on a string in JS. Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript/247261#247261

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve after converting it to String...Inorder to convert it to json use JSON.serialize() method

Comment: I have a question. The base64 data i receive is of word document. Does it matter when decoding?

Comment: @ForceDeveloper : I want to read the word document and then parse the content after which i will be creating/deleting records. So I want to parse the data basically. But the data i have is base64. So finding way to get the actual data. And thank you for your response.

Comment: why not use the `EncodingUtil.base64decode(yourBase64Blob)` so you can manipulate it as a string?  Then you can use all the string methods...

Answer (score 5):

A docx file is actually a zip file (or more precisely an [Open Office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) file), which is a binary file containing text files. There is no Apex native support for unzipping files to get at the contents within e.g. document.xml. However in this two part [blog series](http://andyinthecloud.com/2012/11/04/handling-office-files-and-zip-files-in-apex-part-1/) you can find two alternative approaches to unzipping and accessing the docx contents, both still native to the platform (no third party services). Source code is linked in the blog. Once you have the document.xml file, you can use the built in Apex XML parser.

**Option 1 : Unzip via Static Resoruce**

**NOTE:** If you have the .docx file as an attachment already you can skip the first screen.

[image]

[image]

**Option 2: Unzip via jszip library**

**NOTE:** This shows a .xlsx file, though the process is the same for docx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see you are already using the EncodingUtil Class from Salesforce.  Why not use this class to decode your base64 data into a string so you can use any and all string methods to parse it how you like?

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm

```
Name            Arguments             Return Type       Description
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
base64Decode    String inputString    Blob              Converts a Base64-encoded String to a Blob representing its normal form.
base64Encode    Blob inputBlob        String            Converts a Blob to an unencoded String representing its normal form.
```